# How to get jQuery popup asking user to log in or register if they are not logged in?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have some jQuery and AJAX code that performs an action. If a user id is not passed in, and there isn't one in the session, I want to make a dialog box for the user to ask them to register  or log in.

Is there a way to do that in jQuery?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes!  Use [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/).  Specifically, see their [dialog section](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).  I'm presuming you know how to add a function on ajax success with jquery's ajax methods (where you'll need to tell the dialog to display), let me know if that is not the case and you need help with these.